# Elasticsearch - Kibana - How to attach a volume while containers running

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana, docker-volume

I currently have a docker compose yml file consisting of elasticsearch + kibana.

These 2 containers have been running for a while and have swelled up nicely to about 600 GB.

**Problem - Legacy:** Someone forgot to mount a volume under elastic.

What does this mean for us?... If the container is restarted, yml file is modified and redone etc. all data is lost that shouldn't happen.

**Question:** How can I attach a volume under the currently running container **without losing data**?

I have tried several things, but I am not satisfied with any of them.

---

1. Using docker commit

- a. `docker ps -a`
- b. `docker commit <containerid> <newimagename>`
- c. `docker run -ti -v <volumeName>:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data <newimagename> /bin/bash`

**Problem:** The docker commit will make a "shadowcopy" and this action takes a long time. (10 GB = 10 minutes | 600 GB = 400-600 minutes)

2. Using docker cp

- a. Create a dummy container
- b. Attach a volume under it
- c. Start copying from the existing container to the host
- d. Start copying from the host to the dummy container
- e. Stop the existing container
- f. Attach the volume and start the container

**Problem:** The docker cp also takes a lot of time and the data is not saved from start to finish to the volume.

---

**Main question and problem:**
In my context, this means that from the start time of the docker cp or the docker commit (e.g. 12/12/2023 07:00 AM) to the end time (e.g. 12/12/2023 03:00 PM), the data is lost and can't saved to the volume or inside the container.

What is the best, fastest and least data-lossy way to save data in volume?

**Important:** There is very little downtime, this is a PROD environment.

**<sub><sup>Of course, the last sentence raises a few questions, but let's not get off the point we have lots of backup.</sup></sub>**

Comment: This question isn't really about programming, and I've voted to close it correspondingly.  In an Elasticsearch context specifically, though: could you start a second Elasticsearch instance with the correct settings, and then use Elasticsearch's replication capabilities to live copy all of the data to the new instance?  This will probably take substantially longer than the ~10 hours you show, but the system will be fully operational while the replication is happening.

Comment: Have you access to an S3 repository ? You can create a snapshot to it to be sure to not lose any data.

Comment: Okay @DavidMaze, I can put the question in general terms, if it makes it more community friendly. So, under a running docker container, how can you mount a volume without having to shut it down and/or having a service outage? Is it about programming?

Comment: @Jean-PierreMatsumoto, actually no :( but I have azure and can make a blob storage if it can work.

Comment: Yes it can work : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/repository-azure.html